# Shell script ssh login and execute command inside remote

Tags: bash, shell

**Goal:**

1. login to a remote system, 2) ask for user input, 3) store the first 4 characters of the input string in a file on the remote system.

**What I have:**

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME=someUser
HOST="host1"
SCRIPT="echo Enter the string; read -n 4 str; echo $str > file.txt"
ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME} "${SCRIPT}"
```

**Problem:**

The file.txt does not contain the string- it is empty! If I `echo $str` after the `read`, it seems empty. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Use single-quotes, not double quotes, when assigning to `SCRIPT`.

Comment: Right now, the `$str` is evaluated on what `str` has during the `SCRIPT=` line.

Comment: perfect! thanks @CharlesDuffy